# factoring zero in modulo n

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$. How many different classes $\overline{y}\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ are there, so that
$$\overline{m}\cdot \overline{y}=\overline{0}$$

Each element is either invertible or a factor of the zero. I know that there are $n-\phi(n)$ zero factors in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ ($\phi$ is the Euler's totient function). I have some trouble finding out how many different ways is there to factor a random element $\overline{m}$.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous: given some $\bar{m}$ do you want to know how many $\bar{y}$ are there such that $\bar{m}\bar{y} = \bar{0}$, or do you want to factor it?

Comment: If we look at $\mathbb{Z}_8$ and $\overline{4}$, then there are classes $\overline2$, $\overline{4}$, $\overline6$ and $\overline0$, so that $\overline{4}\cdot \overline{4}=\overline0$ etc.

Comment: Hint: do you know the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $1 \le m \le n$ you need to find all $1 \le y \le n$ such that $my$ is $0$ modulo $n$, that is $n \mid my$.

Now if $m \mid n$, then this is equivalent to $ (n/m) \mid y$, so you have  $(n/m), 2(m/n), \dots, m(n/m) $, that is $m$ classes.

In general, let $m' = \gcd(n,m)$ then $n \mid my$ if and only if $(n/m') \mid y$, so you have $m'$ classes.

Thus, in any case the reply is $\gcd(m,n)$.

Practical note: computing the GCD is a lot simpler than factoring (for large numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you know the prime factorization of $m$, then you have that the set of $y$ is generated by the element that has the complement prime factorization so that when you multiply $y$ and $m$ you get all prime factors of $n$ (with their multiplicity).

Answer (score 0):

Let $d=\gcd(m,n)$, and let $m=dm_1$ and $n=dn_1$. We want the number of integers $y$ in the interval $[0,n-1]$ such that $n$ divides $my$, that is, such that $dn_1$ divides $dm_1y$, that is, such that $n_1$ divides $m_1y$. Since $m_1$ and $n_1$ are relatively prime, we want to find the number of integers $y$ in our interval such that $n_1$ divides $y$. There are $d$ such integers.